# Please help me understand the "while" loop in this JavaScript snippet

Tags: javascript, code-snippets

I have seen a snippet like this for detecting IE in JavaScript using conditional comments.

```
var ie = (function(){

    var undef, v = 3, div = document.createElement('div');

    // the while loop is used without an associated block: {}
    // so, only the condition within the () is executed.

    // semicolons arent allowed within the condition,
    //   so a comma is used to stand in for one
    // basically allowing the two separate statements 
    //   to be evaluated sequentially.

    while (
        div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE '+(++v)+']><i></i><![endif]-->',
        div.getElementsByTagName('i')[0]
    );

    // each time it's evaluated, v gets incremented and
    //   tossed into the DOM as a conditional comment
    // the i element is then a child of the div.

    // the return value of the getEBTN call is used as 
    //   the final condition expression
    // if there is an i element (the IE conditional
    //   succeeded), then getEBTN's return is truthy
    // and the loop continues until there is no 
    //   more i elements.

    // In other words:  ** MAGIC**

    return v > 4 ? v : undef;

}());
```

The above given is the [documented (and slightly improved) version by Paul Irish](https://gist.github.com/527683#gistcomment-7599) on a [snippet by James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/detect-ie-in-js-using-conditional-comments/). I am posting the commented version to let you know that I might need a simpler explanation if anybody may.

I would really like to know **what happens inside the while loop**. I don't understand that.

Comment: Did you read the comments in the code, just below the while loop? They should explain what is happening. I'm not sure what else to explain, maybe you could clarify which parts of the comments you don't understand?

Comment: @Arjan: first tell me whats getEBTN

Comment: it's "get e-button". No, just kidding - `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: @matt: oh jeez. i googled and googled for "getEBTN"... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming I haven't bungled this up horribly) the `while` loop is equivalent to the following:

```
var elt;

do
{
    v++;
    div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + v + ']><i></i><![endif]-->'
    elt = div.getElementsByTagName('i')[0];
} (while elt);
```

---

> does mdc or any good ones cover this while(stmt1, stmt2) thing.

Here's what MDC says about [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while):

> ```
> while (condition)
>     statement
> ```
>
> **`condition`**
> An expression evaluated before each pass through the loop. If this condition evaluates to `true`, `statement` is executed. When condition evaluates to `false`, execution continues with the statement after the `while` loop.

We can find out exactly what an *[expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions)* is in JavaScript from MDC:

> An *expression* is any valid set of literals, variables, operators, and expressions that evaluates to a single value; the value can be a number, a string, or a logical value.
>
> Conceptually, there are two types of expressions: those that assign a value to a variable, and those that simply have a value. For example, the expression `x = 7` is an expression that assigns x the value seven. This expression itself evaluates to seven. Such expressions use *assignment operators*. On the other hand, the expression `3 + 4` simply evaluates to seven; it does not perform an assignment. The operators used in such expressions are referred to simply as *operators*.

If you're feeling brave, you can also check out the [ECMA-262 language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), specifically the following sections:

- **11** Expressions, especially **11.14** Comma Operator ( `,` )
- **12.6.2** The `while` Statement

<sub>Sorry I can't provide direct links as it's all inside of a PDF.</sub>

Comment: @matt: +1. was really looking for some sort of expansion like this. i get this more clearly now. but when will the loop gets exited for a non-ie browser?

Comment: It gets exited immediately after the first pass through since `div.getElementsByTagName('i')` won't find an elements, so `div.getElementsByTagName('i')[0]` will be a falsy value.

Comment: yep this is perfect. i get this. thanks a lot. does mdc or any good ones cover this while(stmt1, stmt2) thing. i am seeing this for the first time.

Comment: Honestly it's pretty gnarly code style. For maintainability purposes I'd never use something that "clever."

Comment: yep. indeed! how would one maintain that sort of thing unless the team is of the highest class of js coders... thank you for your time. i get that code perfectly now. i do love javascript a lot and so it hurts when don't get something. only if i knew getEBTN before-hand :)  thanks once more.

Answer (score 1):

`v` stores the IE version number. It is initialised to 3 so the loop creates strings like the following upon each iteration:

```
// v = 3
<!--[if gt IE 4]><i></i><![endif]-->

// v = 4
<!--[if gt IE 5]><i></i><![endif]-->
```

If you are confused by this part:

```
+(++v)+
```

it simply means, in context, concatenate `'<!--[if gt IE '` with the incremented value of `v` and then concatenate the newly formed string with `']><i></i><![endif]-->'` The increment operator `++` acts to *return* the *incremented* value of `v`, since it *precedes* `v`. If it came after `v`, the current value of `v` would be returned before the increment happens. Mozilla does [a better job](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) of explaining than I do:

> This operator increments (adds one to)
>   its operand and returns a value. If
>   used postfix, with operator after
>   operand (for example, x++), then it
>   returns the value before incrementing.
>   If used prefix with operator before
>   operand (for example, ++x), then it
>   returns the value after incrementing.

thus the first conditional comment created is always 4. The loop continues until `div.getElementsByTagName('i')[0]` does not yield any DOM element, evaluates to `false` and forces the loop to exit.

Comment: +1: no karim. i didnt understand the one liner while loop at first. thanks to matt, i get that now. can you elaborate a little bit on your last line?

Comment: @naveen check out truthy and falsy values in JS. http://blogs.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: @naveen - Since the while loop does not specify a condition, it basically runs until it gets signalled from within the loop to stop, by way of some expression returning a 'falsy' value. Specifically, `div.getElementsByTagName('i')[0]` will return `undefined`, which is considered falsy, along with `null`, `0`, `NaN`, `false` and the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<div><!--[if gt IE 6]><i></i><![endif]--></div>
```

effectively produces a DOM that looks something like

```
<div><i></i></div>
```

in versions of IE > 6. But in earlier versions, and browsers that aren't IE at all, it produces

```
<div></div>
```

So you put in that "if gt IE *version*" HTML and depending on whether the `i` element is part of the DOM, you can figure out whether you're on a version of IE that's greater than `v`. When you get to a value of `v` where the `i` element exists, you're done!